# multi threading issue in C# client/server chat application

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcplistener

> I have a TCP server/client chat program using C#.The server that receives messages from the customer and re-sent to the target.
>
> When  client connects to the server the server creates a new Thread for him.
>
> My problem is that the server is to receive only one message from the customer does not receive any new message from him.
>
> When I do debugging I noticed that the server receives the message and hang in the client Thread but not run again.

The server code:

```
namespace server
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ArrayList alSockets;
    private delegate void UpdateLogCallback(string strMessage);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
        textBox1.Text = "my ip is " + IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString();
        alSockets = new ArrayList();
        Thread thdListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenerThread));
        thdListener.Name = "thdListener";
        
        thdListener.Start();

    }
    public void listenerThread()
    {
        TcpListener tcpc = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,6666);
        tcpc.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Socket HndSoc = tcpc.AcceptSocket();
            if (HndSoc.Connected)
            {
                string str2 = "\n" + HndSoc.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected";
                this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.update2),new object[] {str2});

                lock (this)
                {
                    alSockets.Add(HndSoc);

                }
                ThreadStart thdstHandler = new ThreadStart(handlerThread);
                Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
                thdHandler.Name = "thdHandler";
                thdHandler.Start();
                
             }
            else if(!HndSoc.Connected)
            {
                string str2 = "\n" + HndSoc.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " desconnected";
                this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.update2), new object[] { str2 });

            }

            }
        }
    public void handlerThread()
    {
        byte [] rx = new byte [1024];
        Socket hanso = (Socket) alSockets[alSockets.Count-1];
       NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(hanso);
       // NetworkStream  ns = hanso. 
        ns.Read(rx,0,rx.Length);
   //     textBox1.Text = "\n";
     //   textBox1.Text =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rx);
        string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rx);
       // update(str);
        this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.update), new object[] { str });
       // ns.Close();
       // hanso = null;
        rx = new byte[1024];
        ns.Read(rx, 0, rx.Length);
        
    }
```

And this is client code if needed:

```
namespace simple_clint
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    byte[] tx = new byte[1024];
  //  IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),6666);

    TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6666);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tx = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
        try
        {
            NetworkStream ns = tcp1.GetStream();
            ns.Write(tx, 0, tx.Length);
          //  ns.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: From a quick look, it seems that you need to add a loop into `handlerThread()`.

Comment: thank you a lot to your help..it works.
the loop should be before this line:
 NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(hanso);
and I should remove last two lines

Comment: Also, your server code isn't thread-safe. You can't just modify and read an `ArrayList` from multiple threads without synchronization. You can't just assume that when the handler thread gets around to reading the socket, the correct one is still the last one in the list. Also also, why are you using `ArrayList`? Are you stuck on .NET 1.1 or something? Just use `List<Socket>`. And pass the accepted socket directly to the handler thread method. Asynchronous I/O might also be a better choice than multi-threading - no need to waste threads doing nothing.

Comment: thank you for your notes
I hope to use the  Asynchronous I/O but did not see a good reference about it, if you have a good book or an article I hope to give it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  kajacx. I need to add loop into **handlerThread()**
the new code:

```
public void handlerThread()
    {

            byte[] rx = new byte[1024];
            Socket hanso = (Socket)alSockets[alSockets.Count - 1];
            while (true)
            {
            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(hanso);
            ns.Read(rx, 0, rx.Length);
            string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rx);
            this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.update), new object[] { str });

        }

    }
```

and I remove last two lines